# Do you have to synchronize concurrent collections?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Imagine the following example:
An application starts two threads. The Provider class holds the concurrent collection and writes data to it. The Consumer reads data from the collection.

Is the following code correct or do I have to add synchronization?

```
public class Application{
    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception{
        Provider p = new Provider();
        new Thread(p).start();
        new Thread(new Consumer(p)).start();

        // Make sure the example stops after 60 seconds
        Thread.sleep(1000*60);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

/**The Provider (writes data to concurrent collection)*/
class Provider implements Runnable{

    private ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> map 
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, String>(20, 0.5f, 1);

    public void run(){
         Integer i = 1;
         while(true){
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(500);
             } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
             }
             // Synchronization ?
             map.put(i, i.toString());
             i++;
         }
    }

    public ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> getMap(){
         // Synchronization ?
         return map;
    }

}

/**The Consumer (reads data from concurrent collection)*/
class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private Provider provider;

    public Consumer(Provider p){
        provider = p;
    }

    public void run(){
        while(true){
             try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000);
             } catch (InterruptedException ignore) {
             }
            // Synchronization ?
            ConcurrentMap<Integer, String> m = provider.getMap();
            if(m!=null)
                for(String s: m.values())
                    System.out.print(s); 
            System.out.println();               
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`ConcurrentHashMap` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

> For aggregate operations
>   such as `putAll` and `clear`, concurrent retrievals may
>   reflect insertion or removal of only some entries.  Similarly,
>   Iterators, Spliterators and Enumerations return elements reflecting the
>   state of the hash table at some point at or since the creation of the
>   iterator/enumeration.  They do *not* throw [`ConcurrentModificationException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html).
>   However, iterators are designed to be used by only one thread at a time.
>   Bear in mind that the results of aggregate status methods including
>   `size`, `isEmpty`, and `containsValue` are typically
>   useful only when a map is not undergoing concurrent updates in other threads.
>   Otherwise the results of these methods reflect transient states
>   that may be adequate for monitoring or estimation purposes, but not
>   for program control.

So you don't *need* to synchronize, in that you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Whether you *want* to is up to your program logic.

Answer (score 2):

Mutations of concurrent collections are thread safe, however data consistency is not guaranteed.

The alternate `Collections.synchronized[...]` idiom, in combination with explicit synchronization, will guarantee thread safety **and** data consistency (at the cost of performance).

Comment: Could you give me an example of a data consistency error with a concurrent collection?

Comment: @SteveS. not errors as such, since as [T.J.Crowder](http://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) states, you'd get no `ConcurrentModificationException`. However for instance, the order of operations might differ from expectations. A good catch phrase in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html): `"However, even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access."`